# Do I Really Need to Use A Server Application for Django?

Tags: django, nginx, server, apache2

To this point, I just created and played my Django server in my localhost, like setting up a basic server Linux distro on my another device and testing etc.

However, I also heard of server applications like `apache2` or `nginx`. The thing I wonder about is: Do I really need to use one of them in production? I want to buy (or rent?) a VPS service, then deploy (or publish?) my project on that server. The questions on my head are:

- Running server with `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` means it does not make my application worldwide? An *server application* (or whatever it is) makes it accessible outside?
- Or a *server application* is simply needed for better performance, optimization etc. ?

Simply, why do I need to use `apache2` or `nginx` to deploy my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long story. In few words:

1. Running your project on localhost surely wont make it worldwide accessible, since at least you need a public address for your server, but not a  local one.
2. Speaking honestly it is not a problem to run a site in pro using django built-in server. But, as you can read in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), it is strongly NOT recommended. Why? Because it was developed specially for testing. It is written in python (slow enough for web server) and not suitable for handling multiple queries to the server and it is only a matter of time when it will crash. Of course, there are plenty of other reasons like cache and access settings, redirects and others.

Comment: Yes. One misunderstanding, though: I wanted to say if a server application makes a project globally accessible. I wasn't sure if Django's own runserver thing makes it open. I was wondering if I had bought a VPS and had not install a server application, even if I'd had a public IP address, I would have been inaccesible. However, your second point just made me understand a little bit.

Comment: Surely, it is possible to run a django project without using apache or nginx but only built-in server.

Comment: Small nitpick on your response number 1: using `runserver 0.0.0.0:80` will open the server to listen on all available addresses, not localhost. So as long as the machine has a publicly listed IP address, then `runserver 0.0.0.0:80` will indeed make it publicly available.

Comment: @Joseph yes, you are right, but speaking honestly 0.0.0.0 is not a reserved address for localhost, but one from 127.0.0.0/8 net is. So I haven't meant 0.0.0.0 to be the address.